# Java Web Start ExtensionInstallerService - How to get hold of the install path in the application?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

Java Web Start features a [ExtensionInstallerService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/ExtensionInstallerService.html) that is invoked when the application is installed (and uninstalled). It allows to install "extensions" in a local directory which is provided by the `getInstallPath()` API which reads like this:

> `java.lang.String getInstallPath()`
>
> Returns the directory where the installer is recommended to install the extension in. It is not required that the installer install in this directory, this is merely a suggested path.

I'd now like to know how to get hold of the provided install path in the running Web Start application (what's defined in `application-desc` JNLP element).

I've already checked the system properties of the JVM the application is running in. Lot's of `deployment.*` properties there, but not the install path used by the extension installer. The `ExtensionInstallerService` itself is unavailable in the running application - so not possible to call `getInstallPath()` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.ExtensionInstallerService")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/ServiceManager.html#lookup-java.lang.String-) to get access to an instance of the service, then use its methods as needed.

> Asks the JNLP Client for a service with a given name. The lookup must be idempotent, that is return the same object for each invocation with the same name.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `name` - Name of service to lookup.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> An object implementing the service. `null` will never be returned. Instead an exception will be thrown.
>
> **Throws:**
>
> `UnavailableServiceException` - if the service is not available, or if name is `null`.

### Edit

> I have no problem to lookup `ExtensionInstallerService` in the extension installer class (JNLP element `installer-desc`), but this service is unavailable in the running application (JNLP element `application-desc`).

Huh, had not realised. In any case, while in the extension installer code, offer the user the place to install the extension, then store that path using the [`PersistenceService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/PersistenceService.html).

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted to know. Maybe I should rephrase the question. Nonetheless, I have no problem to lookup `ExtensionInstallerService` in the extension installer class (JNLP element `installer-desc`), but this service is unavailable in the running application (JNLP element `application-desc`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check and revert.

Comment: What an odd API to work with - for desktop apps. Thanks, it works!

Comment: *"What an odd API to work with - for desktop apps."* I think it was *originally* designed for JWS apps. that need to work within the tightest security restrictions (i.e. sand-boxed). Was especially useful for applets launched using JWS.